# Stopwatch in Flutter only shows elapsed time, not continuous time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stopwatch in my flutter app - but unfortunately, no matter how many SetStates I add, it only seems to show the elapsed time. I need it to show the continuous second changes.

Here is my code:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

String elapsedTime = "";

var timeSoFar;

setTime() {
  setState(() {
    timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(timeSoFar);
  });
}

transformMilliSeconds(int milliseconds) {
  int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
  int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
  int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

  String  minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  String  secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

  return "$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
}
```

Then within my widget tree:

```
Text(elapsedTime),
```

What am I doing wrong? I really need to see the seconds change - I do not want just the elapsed time.

I'v tried this:

```
watch.start();
setState(() {
  setTime();
  print(elapsedTime);
});
```

Comment: What does "continuous time" mean?  Could you elaborate about what you want?

Comment: Hello sir, continuous just means the seconds changing. All that happens now is that the user has to trigger the screen or time to be updated. No. I want the time to be updated automatically.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is - this thing needs a ticker.. that's because set state will only update the current value whenever it is invoked. But a Ticker will do the trick. How do I do this with a ticker?

Comment: Good article here, not only showing how to do it, but discussing the performance issues of continuous updates. https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-fast-is-flutter-i-built-a-stopwatch-app-to-find-out-9956fa0e40bd

Comment: If you want to trigger an update at regular intervals, you can use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it seems that you'd like to continuously update the time elapsed once the Timer has started. The reason why the Timer resets is because it's being disposed automatically when not in use on the main thread. What you'd like to have here is to create a separate service that will handle the Timer updates similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228993/how-to-implement-persistent-stopwatch-in-flutter).